# imaging source dmk31 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, camera, configure

I have an imaging source dmk31 camera and I want it to work on ubuntu 11.04.
it is a firewire camera, but I'm using it with esxpress card
the adapter is already configured, but still I can't get video.
I installed kino, and I can choose the express card port as source, but then I can't see any camera connected to it.
can someone tell me how to manage it?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Information about how to make TIS cameras work under Linux can be found here:

http://www.unicap-imaging.org/tis_devices_en.htm